# How do I use POST when making a login form in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a simple login form, just for testing purposes, but with `GET` it showed the user credentials in the `URL`. So I searched online and found that you need to use `POST` instead of `GET`, because `POST` would not display it in the `URL`. I'm using the Express-Generator setup, with little to no changes to the base code. I'm just not sure how to add this `POST` thing because it keeps saying "`Cannot POST /`".

Bin -> www.js (Code generated by Express Generator)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('poppyplains:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Routes -> Index.js (Generated by Express-Generator

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('post request inc')
})

module.exports = router;
```

public -> index.html (Form part is custom, the rest of the code is done by Express-Generator

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Express</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Express</h1>
  <p>Welcome to Express</p>

  <form method="post" action="/">
    <div class="formTestAuth">
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
      <br>
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm very new to using ExpressJS so I hope someone finds the time to answer my question and give some advice on how to fix the issue. Have a good day!

Comment: You have an `app` and a `router` in your Router/Index.js file, but you need only the `router`. It is `router.post`, not `app.post`.

Comment: Wow, great. I tried it before and it didn't seem to work, but now I changed it back, did a full restart, and it works! Thanks a ton!